# Detect Gestures on Fingerprint Sensor-Android

Tags: android, gesture, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I have authenticated user using `authenticate()` method in my app. I was looking through documentation regarding gestures on Finger-Print Sensor but couldn't find any class pertaining to gestures. Is there any class regarding same which detects gestures like long Press,Tap, etc on finger print sensor.

I went through `FingerprintManager` class & [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) but couldn't find much info regarding gestures.

Answer (score 6):

From android O onward you can use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/FingerprintGestureController.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to directly interact with the sensor and listen for touch events or something similar. The only info you will get is if the user moved the finger too fast during the authentication process, if the sensor is dirty or if an unknown fingerprint was recognised.

For more information on how the fingerprint stuff is implemented on Android, you can check out the following page: https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal.html